# Combination from many sets

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ sets. For example:
$A = \{a,b\}$
$B = \{c\}$
$C = \{d,e\}$
$D = \{f\}$

And I have to calculate how many 3-element combinations are there. There's also a condition that I can use only 1 element from each set. So for example there is $\{a,c,d\}$, $\{b,e,f\}$, $\{a,c,f\}$ etc.
Any ideas?

Comment: 2*1*2 for ABC, 2*1*1 for ABD, ACD 2*2*1 etc. You get the gist.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thank you!